# How to use boost::thread::at_thread_exit or call a function when thread is done

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

This is a minimal code to illustrate what I need. It doesn't work, because (as rightly the error message says when compiling) at_thread_exit is not a member of boost::thread. I know is related to the namespace this_thread, I've been going through the documentation at the boost page, but cannot follow how to use at_thread_exit. I haven't been able to find any simple example of how to use it using google.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class A{
    public:
    void callme(){
        int a = 1;
    }
    void runThread()  {
        boost::thread td(&A::callme,this);
        td.at_thread_exit(&A::done,this);
        td.join();
    }
    void done() {
        std::cout << "I am done!!!\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    A *a = new A();
    a->runThread();
    delete a;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: By the time you reach the line after `boost::thread`, the thread could be already exited.  The lack of API reflects the badness of the idea, I suspect.

Comment: and how would you call a function once a thread has finished? In the case that needed that, what would you do? my thread runs for a few secons for sure, is doing some heavy numerical calculations.

Comment: @Yakk is right, the most that could be done is to attach a function to call on `join()`, but that's rather silly. However, you can use an object's destructor inside the thread. Alternatively, wrap the thread functor in another functor that does that. Other than that, don't use `new` unnecessarily.

Comment: Why not pass a function that both does `callme` and `done`, and pass *that* to `boost::thread`?  In C++11, a lambda.

Comment: @Yakk - Agreed.  Instead of "thread does 'a', then we do 'b' when it exits", just do "thread does 'a', then thread does 'b'".

Comment: @Yakk, you are right. If you write that as an answer and expand it a little bit I'll mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boost::thread td([this]{
  callme();
  done();
});
```

`at_thread_exit` only works within the same thread; it would require sychronization otherwise, and that would make every thread pay for it when only some threads use it.